# open image from the web with python image library

Tags: python

I am new to python and am working with python image library. I just want to be able to open an image from the web and get the histogram from this image. Unfortunately I get the error `File "new.py", line 1
    from PIL import Image import urllib` and it does not work. Any idea how to get this working?

```
from PIL
import Image
import urllib

im = Image.open(urllib.urlopen("http://fmforums.com/forum/uploads/profile/photo-thumb-57725.jpg"))
im = im.convert("P")

print im.histogram()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the first two lines of your program.

```
from PIL
import Image
```

should be

```
from PIL import Image
```

For more information about importing in python, see [here](http://www.effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm).

Comment: thank you that worked now i get `AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute 'seek'
` any ideas?

Comment: @Mr.1.0 That error has nothing to do with the code that you are showing here. Please make a new question for it, then I (and others) will be happy to help.